# Create a Dataframe priority/rank column based on conditions over multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Suppose I have a pandas Dataframe,

```
  Name    thick  prio
  Aabc1     20     1
  Babc2     21     1
  Cabc3     22     1
  Aabc4     23     1
  Axyz1     20     2
  Bxyz2     21     2
  Axyz3     22     2
```

I need to create a dataframe column such a way that expected output will be

```
  Name    thick  prio  newPrio
  Aabc1     20     1     1
  Babc2     21     1     3
  Cabc3     22     1     4
  Aabc4     23     1     2
  Axyz1     20     2     5
  Bxyz2     21     2     7
  Axyz3     22     2     6
```

The logic behind this is:
**1st group names based on thickness (ascending order) and priority. Then check the `prio` column, for example, 1, there are multiple names, if a name starts with A give them 1st priority, if B then 2nd and if C then third. Then go to the `prio` 2 and do the same thing. In this way, I would like to create a `newPrio` column.**

I have tried it and it is working partially
`x['newPrio'] = x.sort_values(['Name', 'thick', 'prio'])['thick'].index + 1`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sort_values` by `prio` then `Name` and `thick`:

```
rank = df.sort_values(['prio', 'Name', 'thick']).index
df['newPrio'] = pd.Series(range(1, len(df)+1), index=rank)
print(df)

# Output
    Name  thick  prio  newPrio
0  Aabc1     20     1        1
1  Babc2     21     1        3
2  Cabc3     22     1        4
3  Aabc4     23     1        2
4  Axyz1     20     2        5
5  Bxyz2     21     2        7
6  Axyz3     22     2        6
```

Comment: Thanks for your point @Corralien. But I guess argsort() is applicable to certain things. If I have a name starts with some number, say '2abc1' or '5abc1' and I would like to give priority to '5abc1'. Then will it work ?

Comment: You can use the `key` parameter to give a custom function or use `ascending=[True, False, True]`

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) with [`Index.argsort`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.argsort.html) for positions of indices:

```
df['newPrio'] = df.sort_values(['prio', 'Name', 'thick']).index.argsort() + 1
print (df)
    Name  thick  prio  newPrio
0  Aabc1     20     1        1
1  Babc2     21     1        3
2  Cabc3     22     1        4
3  Aabc4     23     1        2
4  Axyz1     20     2        5
5  Bxyz2     21     2        7
6  Axyz3     22     2        6
```

If want sorting by first letter only:

```
 df['newPrio'] = (df.assign(Name = df['Name'].str[0])
                   .sort_values(['prio', 'Name', 'thick']).index.argsort() + 1)
```

Or if first letter if is possible converting to numeric:

```
 df['newPrio'] = (df.assign(Name = df['Name'].str[0].astype(int))
                   .sort_values(['prio', 'Name', 'thick']).index.argsort() + 1)
```

Comment: Thanks for your point. But I guess ```argsort()``` is applicable to certain things. If I have a name starts with some number, say '2abc1' or '5abc1' and I would like to give priority to '5abc1'. Then will it work ?

Comment: @Manglu - `argsort` working with indices. So if `sort_values` return your expected order soluton working well.